# Method to return the lowest filename number not being used

Tags: python, django

I have a Django site where users upload and have the option to delete files. There will be a lot of files that will have the same logical name so I append numbers to them:

> ```
> foo/bar/file.mp3 foo/bar/file2.mp3...
> ```

I needed a method that would return the lowest file number not currently being used. I have a working example here, but it feels wrong and ugly and I don't know if there is an easier way of doing it. If I ran the method on the examples above, it would return "1" so I know I can make the next file `foo/bar/file1.mp3`.

```
def get_num(self, files):
        """function to extract the lowest file number to save as, returns string. Takes a list as input"""
        nums = []
        for f in files:
            # Call the unicode function which should return the string path
            match = re.findall("([\d]+)\.[\w]+", f.__unicode__())
            if match:
                nums.append(int(match[0]))
            else:
                nums.append(0)

        for i in range(len(nums) + 1):
            if i not in nums:
                if i == 0:
                    return ""
                else:
                    return str(i)
```

Comment: Could you use a random string generator using 15 digits or something like that? This would give you a unique key with less computational overhead and provided that you give enough digits the odds of duplication are extremely slim. You have a set string size so that's easy enough to parse off on document display and download. (I'm assuming you're already parsing off the number identifier)

Answer (score 5):

When you don't need indexes or ordering, it is generally a good idea to use a set over a list because its membership testing is more efficient.  That means, use `nums = set()` instead of `nums = []`, and use `nums.add(...)` instead of `nums.append(...)`.  That's all you need to change.

---

I'm not sure why you are accessing the special method directly.  Why not use `unicode(f)` instead of `f.__unicode__()`?

---

Python has its own version of something that is often called a *ternary operator*.  Its format is `truth_value if some_condition else false_value`.  Therefore, you can replace your first `if` and `else` blocks with this:

```
nums.append(int(match[0]) if match else 0)
```

(It would be `nums.add(...)` if you decide to use a set.)

and your second `if` and `else` blocks with this:

```
return "" if i == 0 else str(i)
```

Comment: [Python internally caches recently used regexps](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L277), there is no need to precompile them.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski: Interesting, thanks for the info.  Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Test file existence, testing numbers with ever larger steps.

In pseudo-code, for powers of two (but three would be nice too, or fibonacci numbers):

```
find free file number (name)
     find file with number (name, 1, 10_000)

""" start: assumed existing, end: assumed not existing """
find file with number (name, start, end)
    if start + 1 >= end then end
    for i in 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ... where start + i < end
        find where file with number=(start + i) exists
               and file with number=(start + next i) >= end or does not exist
            then find file with numer (name, start + i, start + next i)
```

Worst case:  \$(^2\log n)^2/2\$ hence \$O((\log n)^2)\$